# How to get sum of sum in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query for find apiCount and javascriptCount now i want to one count as apiCount + javascriptCount How can i do that please help me.I try to find many solution on google but i can't get exactly solution of my problem.

```
SELECT  display , 
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) apiCount, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) javascriptCount 
FROM error 
WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY display
```

this is my query i want to sum of apiCount and javascriptCount in same query.

Comment: I've noticed that the expression `occurance` doesn't have a grouping function. That means the value is randomly chosen from all the rows that are selected.

Comment: @jarlh Then expression I talked about has been removed three hours ago. You can still find it in some of the answers.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, I understand. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '+' operator to make it total
Or you can combined the both logic to count it

```
SELECT  display , 
SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+SUM(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 totalCount,occurance 
 FROM error WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY display
```

OR

```
SELECT  display , 
SUM(CASE WHEN (category i=2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401)) OR category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 totalCount,occurance 
 FROM error WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY display
```

Comment: You second suggestion won't work because the `statusCode` is also checked when the `category` is 1.

Comment: That's better, however `category in=2` has a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two `CASE` expressions to get the combined sum:

```
SELECT  display , 
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) apiCount, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) javascriptCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401) OR category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalCount, 
  occurance 
FROM error 
WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY display
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your original query up in a derived table. Then you can calculate apiCount + javascriptCount:

```
select dt.*, apiCount + javascriptCount
from
(
    SELECT  display , 
      SUM(CASE WHEN category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) apiCount, 
      SUM(CASE WHEN category = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) javascriptCount,
      occurance 
    FROM error 
    WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
    GROUP BY display
) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql the simplest you can `SUM` with the condition, the condition established add one, otherwise didn't add.

You can try this.

```
SELECT display, 
       SUM(category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401)) apiCount, 
       SUM(category = 1 ) javascriptCount,
       SUM((category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401)) OR category = 1) totalCount,
       occurance 
FROM error 
WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
GROUP BY display
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try the following query.

```html
SELECT  display , 
  SUM(CASE WHEN 
   (category = 2 AND (statusCode != -1 AND statusCode != 400  AND statusCode != 401)) -- apiCount
   OR (category = 1) -- javascriptCount
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) apiCount_and_javascriptCount,
  occurance 
 FROM error 
  WHERE  `occurance` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) GROUP BY display
```